# Youtube data api (Contnet ID) errors on composition asset creation

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, composition

Our app is in production for 2 years and has been able to create all 3 music video assets(music video, sound recording and composition) using YT data API requests. Since last week, we are receiving an error on composition asset create request. Music Video and Sound Recording asset create requests are working fine as usual.

YT API Error:

```
vagrant$ curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "authorization: Bearer ya29.XXXXXXXX_O3pRQWtbrQ5dHn5BV6SiiGxkawq26LksyUy1LjwtG27Vs9e9-XXXX" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" -H "content-length: 193" -d '{"type":"composition","onBehalfOfContentOwner":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","metadataMine":{"customId":"9c3e6533a06cac4e","writer":["DeAndre \"Drizzo Man\" White, Daniel Kováč"],"title":"Ready"}}' "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets?onBehalfOfContentOwner=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) YouTube Data API - Errors, that `forbidden (403) error` means:

> forbidden (403) - Access forbidden. The request may not be properly
>   authorized.

So try to check if you properly implement the [OAuth authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) in your project.

Comment: Authorization is good since we are able to perform other actions using the same credentials. It is certainly something to do with creating composition assets api. 

For instance, we can get the policies associated with an existing composition asset:

$ curl -X GET -H "content-type: application/json" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "authorization: Bearer ya29.xxxxxxxx" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/policies?onBehalfOfContentOwner=xxxxxxx"

{
 "kind": "youtubePartner#policyList",
 "items": [
      ......
   ]

  }
]
}